# Getting an error "Missing artifact com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.66" in maven pom.xml file.Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have added the required dependencies in maven pom.xml file.

- Downloaded the dependencies in pom.xml file via Maven Install option
- Updated the project.

After updating the project, i found the error message "Missing artifact com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.66" in pom.xml file.

I have tried including the dependency of jcommander 1.66 version in pom.xml file but there is no change.

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not only need the dependencies in your POM, but also the *transitive* dependencies, i.e. their dependencies, the dependencies of their dependencies and so on.

This is why you let Maven connect to standard Maven repositories like MavenCentral. Except for unavailable artifacts, manual installation of artifacts should be avoided.